# Is this possible to use proxy on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, https, proxy

Lets imagine that I have GAE-hosted java application.

Is this possible to do HTTP/HTTPS requests via third party proxy (SOCKS or http) from this application? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there who is wondering...

The answer is no, use of proxies are not permitted on GAE. Code like this:

```
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("{proxy_ip_here)}", {proxy_port_here}));
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://{some_address_here}").openConnection(proxy);
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```

... will work on standard Jave SE and will fail on GAE with:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Google App Engine does not support the use of proxies.
```